# Very low-power ESP8266-based motion detector

Tags: esp8266, low-power, motion

I'm building a new schematic to set up an ESP8266 m-based motion detector which should only work during the night.

My goals are:

- Use an RTC to store time and read time when ESP starts up (if not in time window, it will go back to sleep).
- The ESP8266 will be coded to disable WiFi on boot to speed up the boot process, and to limit battery drain
- The ESP8266 will only connect to WiFi when within the time window to send a signal to MQTT

I've made multiple schematics and PCBs already, but the trial-and-error is starting to cost a lost of money, so I'd like some experts to review of my schematic.

The schematics can be found here: https://we.tl/t-JaEAZL9Poa

In case some folks want to see the schematics directly, here they are:

[image: Combined view of the schematic]

For the expects amongst you, would you bother taking a quick look and based on your experience tell me if there are any major issues? Especially with focus on the latching circuit and the boot high/low interference I may occur when the ESP starts up that may compromise my complete schematic.

Comment: Stackexchange is designed for specific questions and answers. you can narrow down the question to your previous mistakes, join a forum and post your project there for general guidance, or pay an expert

Comment: Well, it's impossible to know from schematics if it works or not. The PDF looks more like a block diagram how to wire some modules together.

Comment: buy a solderless breadboard for doing development work

Comment: there is absolutely no reason why anyone should have to download a file to understand your question ... see this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638651/can-anyone-check-my-schematic-and-pcb-its-supposed-to-control-electrical-appli

Comment: The commercial designs I’ve seen use a small very low power micro to power up the esp8266.  I think that is telling us something.

Comment: You’ve used one of my most despised schematic design traits:  blobs of circuitry on a single page linked only via net labels, instead of wires which COMMUNICATE MEANING, GRAPHICALLY, and thus put the onus on every viewer of your schematic to do all the work of piecing it together in their head.  Won’t do.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing in the past, then an expert told me this is not how to do things and told me to split it up into different graphics... :(
Everyone seems to have its own opinion and no one seems to be able to provide help...

I'll see if I can put it together with wires when I find some time...

Comment: Net labels versus full wiring is a balance act. I favor net labels when some signal enters or exit a confined group or function. You can make it easier for the reader by having inputs come from the left and outputs to the right.

Comment: _"I've made multiple schema's and PCB's already, but the trial and error starts to cost a lost of money."_ What did your previous iterations look like (schematics)? What were the exact issues you had with them (scope plots would be a bonus)? Weren't you able to modify them, or at least gain knowledge for the next iteration? And most of all: it would better fit the nature of this Q&A site, if you'd split the issues into separate well defined questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few design issues that I see.

1. The VBAT isn't connect to anything other than to the 3.3V output of PowerU1 LDO. And as far as I can see, the LDO output isn't connect to VCC in any way, so your board isn't powered.
2. Maximum operating voltage of ESP12-S is 3.6V, you seems to thinking of power the ESP12-S directly with VBAT. Not sure what type of battery you are using, but if you are thinking of power the ESP12-S with 3.7V LiPo battery, it will exceed the ESP12-S 3.6V maximum operating voltage, furthermore, when the battery is fully charge it could be as high as 4.2V.
3. So VBAT should be connected via the input of the LDO instead of the output of the LDO, but you need to have protection diodes so that when VBAT and VIN both are trying to power the board, it won't damage the components.
4. The MCP1700 LDO is a wrong part in meeting the peak current requirements of ESP12-S when WiFi is turn on, it will result in sudden voltage drop and reboot. Suggest to uses [AP2112K](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2112.pdf) or something equivalent.
5. If you are using ESP12-S, the pull-up, pulldown resistors ESPR5-8 are not required as those has been built-in inside the ESP12-S module. For more detail, please refer to [ESP12-S datasheet](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/docs/esp-12s_product_specification_en.pdf).

Comment: This is wonderful feedback. Thank you soooo much !

Comment: I indeed have multiple different powers i'm playing with.
I use a 1400mAh LiPo battery, with peak at 4.2V (BAT). That one I drop to 3.3V using my LDO with output VCC-IN.
The VCC-IN powers my motion detector and is also the input power for my latching circuit.
When motion is triggered, the latching circuit puts VCC out that powers the board.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the feedback received, I've updated my schematic.
I've also reconnected everything without nets to ensure I don't get those complaints anymore. It should make it more readable to those who wished connected nets. ;-)

[image: Updated schematic]